What does Lutheranism say about God's soul?
The question is: According to Lutheranism, does God have a soul?
Understandably, the answer will have to incorporate the Lutheran definition of 'soul' and, if yes, whether it differs from the 'human soul'.
I apologize for the phrasing of the 'title'. The original was being wrongly resisted as a duplicate by the bot.
Related:  A question for Roman Catholicism about the soul of God?, According to Eastern Orthodoxy does God have a soul?, What is the Methodist position on God's soul?, Do Baptists say God has a soul?, Does God have a soul according to Presbyterians?, Do Anglicans think God has a soul?, Do Pentecostals teach that God has a soul?
